# Can I use SimpleSAMLPhp as a service provider to test my SAML identityprovider which is written in C#?

Tags: c#, saml

I have implemented a SAML compliant  Identity Provider in C#. Can any one tell me whether I can use SimpleSAMLPhp as a Service provider to test my identity provider? OR tell me other products that I can use for my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just configure it to run as a SP.

Or look at [Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/).

Comment: Inorder to test my SAML Identity Provider, should I host the Identity Provider in public domain? Foe me I have used SAML ECP profile not a Web SSO. So please suggest me a SAML service provider to test my Identity Provider which supports ECP profile?